# Equivalent one-output of a SIMO converter

Tags: circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply, circuit-design, power-electronics, switching-regulator

The single-inductor multiple-output (SIMO) converter below is a dc-dc converter with one input, one inductor and n outputs Vo1, Vo2,..., Von and load currents Io1, Io2,...,Ion.

Is there any theory, method to represent the SIMO by an equivalent single-inductor, single-input and single-output with equivalent output voltage and load current Voeq and Ioeq?

[image]

The image is taken from [here](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20040201281).

Answer (score 0):

Switches S1 to Sn direct the stored energy to one out of the n outputs i.e. the switches act like a  demultiplexor so if you want to model a single output then insert a time delay after the charge and discharge part of the switching cycle. Put another way, if there are ten outputs then each output only gets serviced in its allotted cycle and the rest of the time is just dead time so if the charge discharge cycle last 10 us wait 90 us until beginning the cycle again.

I’m not going to consider what happens if there is still energy in the inductor when the cycle starts for the analysed output because it gets messy.

Comment: I think your approach is seperating each output and operating them independently. Actually I am looking for equivalent single output voltage and single output load current so I can compensate and control input switches as a single-inductor single output converter.

Comment: @anhnha you've lost me on that, sorry.

Comment: I appreciate your input. Maybe I need to edit the question.